# How to get the exact size of the array

Tags: c++

I declared the array in this way:

```
int arr[50];
```

Inside the code I used just 10 from this size for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    arr[i] += 5;
}
```

Now I want to get the exact size of the array that should be(10). I used

```
int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
```

But this gave me the all size of the array that represent in 50.

Comment: Unfortunately C++ does not work this way. Nothing in C++ tracks which values in an array were properly initialized. You must implement this logic yourself. If your code initialized only `arr[2]` but did not set `arr[0]` or `arr[1]` what would you expect this hypothetical function to give you, and why, exactly?

Comment: Use this:  `int size = 10;`.  But, `arr[i]+=5;` is doing a `+=` on uninitialized `arr`, unless `arr` is a global variable.  (C++ treats globals and statics a little different from other variables.)

Comment: *"I want to get the exact size of the array that should be(10)"* -- No, the size of the array is 50. Perhaps you mean the size of the *used* portion? (Or the *logical* size? There are a few ways to phrase this, but "size of the array" is reserved for the size given in the definition.)

Comment: If you really want to mimic what you would do in C, then `#define MYARRSZ 50` and then `int arr[MYARRSZ];` then throughout that translation unit you can refer to `MYARRSZ` and get the number of elements in your array. You can do something similar in C++ using `constexpr int MYARRSZ = 50;`, but that doesn't change the fact that a plain-old-array can only report its size *in the scope where it was declared* using `sizeof arr / sizeof *arr`.

Comment: Clearly what you want is a `std::vector<int>` not an array. A vector can do all the things you want (like starting at one size but changing it's size later) but an array cannot.

Comment: Just forget C-style arrays exist in the language and use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead and call the `.size()` member function.

Answer (score 5):

A raw C-style array like what you have shown will not keep track of how many values you've "used" in it. You would have to manually keep track of that.

If the tag is correct and you are using C++ (as opposed to C compiled with a C++ compiler), then I'd suggest if you need a variable number of elements in your array and need to know how many are in it, you should use `std::vector` instead of a raw C array.

Also, your code is adding `5` to the first ten elements of an *uninitialized* array. The initial values in the array are indeterminate, so the result will be unpredictable.

Comment: Yes, so I will use vector. Thank you Chris!

Comment: Wouldn't _initialized_ be a proper term than "used".

Answer (score 1):

> But this gave me the all size of the array that represent in 50.

That is good, since nothing shrunk the original array. You read 10 values from it - and that's it. If you want another collection of values, you'll have to create it.

Example:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int arr[50]{}; // initialized, processed and dealt with however you'd like

    // Inside the code I used just 10 from this size for example:
    int just_ten[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        just_ten[i] = arr[i] + 5;
    }
    
    std::cout << std::size(just_ten) << '\n'; // 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say, *Now I want to get the exact size of the array that should be(10)*, the exact size of the array is 50, not 10. 10 is the size of the *initialized* portion of the array, which is what you want. So, to do that, all you need is the number of elements you are initializing in the array, which is just `i`, so you could implement the following code below.

Acknowledging Chris that a great alternative to a C-style array is to use an `std::vector`. But, in the *exact* same case as yours, what you could do is declare `i` in the outer scope and use it later to get the initialized "portion" of the array.
Like this:

```
int arr[50]{};
size_t i;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    arr[i] += 5;
}

std::cout << i;
```

But, this of course would work in only a case that is exactly the same as the case given by you. But, using an `std::vector` is more ideal in larger-scale programs, which Chris suggested.

Comment: Note that `std::size_t` would be a more appropriate type than `int`.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is create an array of [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) elements:

```
std::optional<int> arr[50];
```

That way, every element will contain additional data which will specify whether the element contains a valid value or not. All elements are initialized to the state of not containing a valid value.

You can then assign values to some of these elements, and then count the number of elements in the array that contain a valid value. Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

int main()
{
    std::optional<int> arr[50];

    //assign values to some elements of the array
    arr[4]  = 20;
    arr[38] = 14;
    arr[42] = 19;

    //count the number of elements containing valid values
    int count = 0;
    for ( auto& elem : arr )
    {
        if ( elem )
            count++;
    }

    std::cout <<
        "The array contains " <<
        count <<
        " elements with valid values." <<
        '\n';
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
The array contains 3 elements with valid values.
```